# WordPress media library, change existing URLS to AWS s3

Tags: wordpress, web, media-library

I am having trouble mass changing the locations in WordPress for the images.

I have ran this request in PHPMyAdmin

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, ‘http://www.oldsite.com’,’http://www.newsite.com’);
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, ‘http://www.oldsite.com’, ‘http://www.newsite.com’);
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, ‘http://www.oldsite.com’, ‘http://www.newsite.com’);
```

Where **newsite.com** is the url for the S3 bucket.

However, when I go into the media library for wordpress none of the images are loading. When I click an image, the URL for that image is still **oldsite.com/wp-content/uploads/...**

Can someone please help me make wordpress media manager use my s3 url instead?

p.s I have just over 12 thousand images. Would ideally not want to do this manually.

Comment: Excellent for search & replace on Wordpress, make sure to backup before using this tool https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: That doesnt work for me: The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found. Plugin install failed.

Comment: ignore me. Didnt read correcty